# program hangs when using windows 32bit serial communications

Tags: c

written below is a crude code i wrote for accessing a serial port. attached to that port is a microcontroller that sends me data and having a baud rate of 57600. i ran the code once and got results but after closing the window, my computer hanged. i pressed ctrl+alt+del and saw that under processes my program was still running. i cant close it too.

```
int n = 20;
char szBuff[20 + 1] = {0};

HANDLE hSerial;
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts={0};
DWORD dwBytesRead = 20;

dcbSerialParams.DCBlength=sizeof(DCB);

hSerial = CreateFile("COM5",
                 GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                 0,
                 0,
                 OPEN_EXISTING,
                 FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                 0);


if(hSerial==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
  if(GetLastError()==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
  {
    puts ("cannot open port!");
  }

  puts ("invalid handle value!");                                 
}

if (!GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams)) 
{
  puts ("error getting state");
}

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate=CBR_57600;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize=8;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits=ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity=NOPARITY;

if(!SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams))
{
  puts ("error setting port state");
}


while (1)
{

  if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
     puts ("serial read error fail!");
  } 

  else
  {
     printf ("%s\n" , szBuff);
  }

}
```

Comment: you're using `while 1`, how do you expect your program to close?

Comment: i want to continuously read the data from the port, i suppose i am doing it wrong. can you tell me how i can do this more efficiently?

Comment: it's not per se wrong, but you need some way to tell the program when to stop.. eg instead of `puts ("serial read error fail!");` use `puts ("serial read error fail!"); break;` this should already (if I'm correct) exit the loop when the serial device fails or is disconnected.

Comment: oh nice catch sir. reading works fine now. i do however have a new problem. the way im sending data off the microcontroller is by this format: $A.B.C$ followed by a newline. so its 7 bytes right? i set the 3rd argument for readfile to 20, greater than 7 bytes so that i can succesfully read all of the data string. however reading sometimes misses a few characters. instead of reading $A.B.C$ i read in one line $A.B.C and in the line after that $ (a hidden'\n'). how can i fix this?

Comment: @user582485: It's a valid question. But you put it in the comment secion of another question. Please don't; there's no good place for answers. Make it another question instead. StackOverflow doesn't have a limit on the number of questions you may ask.

Comment: @stihn - You should have made that an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a buggy serial port driver.  See [Why do some process stay in Task Manager after they've been killed?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/23/192531.aspx).  When you kill your program, it doesn't go away until all of its pending I/O operations have been canceled.

Comment: Probably is, but he's still trying to read from it even after the port goes lame (nothing breaks out of the while loop on error).

Comment: @Tim: A program that that loops forever isn't inherently buggy, it could just be designed to only to end when killed forcefully such as `tail -f`.  And since this program is blocking on I/O, it's not spinning and eating up 100% CPU.

Comment: I do agree, it's likely a buggy driver. I can finally add the +1 to go with my comment now that I have votes again, yippie!

Answer (score 0):

You MUST to define some type of stop to the app if it will loop in a while(1).

Option 1: The microcontroller must send a terminate command or character that you use to break the while.

Option 2: Some type of timeout instead while(1).

Option 3: Catch some signal and then break the while().

And there are a lot of other options.